# Slow seek in MKV videos with FFmpeg C/C++

Tags: ffmpeg, mkv

Seeking in any large MKV H.264 video works very slow.

Call of av_seek_frame() in my code using FFmpeg LibAV takes about 3-10 seconds to jump to a middle position in 1-2 hours video.

I tried all combinations of flags: AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD, AVSEEK_FLAG_BYTE, AVSEEK_FLAG_ANY, AVSEEK_FLAG_FRAME

However VLC seeks very fast in same MVK videos.

Seeking in MP4 H.264 works instantly. The problem is only with MKV.

Latest FFmpeg 4.1.3.

Comment: Not really helpful, but I have some Vorbis mkvs that also have problems seeking. They were converted from Youtube mkvs with ffmpeg. They are A LOT slower than the seeking timing you are getting, and if I seek the mkv to 0, the mkv completely hangs after 5 minutes and 50 seconds. The best way around it is probably to use ffmpeg to convert the files to another format.